# HTML5 meta tags & W3 Validator

Tags: html, validation

I have a question related to HTLM5 meta tags and W3 Validator.

As we all know, there are several meta tags which Validator seems to dislike. This one for example:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

So far I have used this trick:

```
var meta_elem = document.createElement('meta');
meta_elem.setAttribute('http-equiv', 'X-UA-Compatible');
meta_elem.setAttribute('content', 'IE=edge,chrome=1');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta_elem);
```

Right now it seems to serve its purpose. W3 Validator knows nothing about meta tag's existence and therefore we get no complainings from there.

But I still have some doubts, so here comes my question: is this actually the correct way for solving that problem? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't make decisions based on the W3C validator. It never gives you the complete picture. It should be used only to trace syntax errors (i.e. linting).

Coming to the question, this isn't really an error. The X- prefix means that this is vendor specific, in this case it's for IE (meaning render in the best version), and for Chrome Frame (the 1 means on).

It's not invalid.

If the validation error is bugging you so much, then you can use the following techniques to achieve the same purpose,

**1. Set HTTP header with PHP**

```
header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1');
```

**2. Using the .htaccess File**

```
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"
```

**3. With IIS web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**4. With C#**

```
Response.AppendHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge,chrome=1");
```

> Latest news from Google says that they will discontinue the use of Google Chrome Frame starting 2014. Hence, you can even do away from this piece of code completely.